# How to get rid of the smell from indoor climbing shoes?

Tags: gear, climbing, footwear, shoes, cleaning

When I go climbing indoors I typically wear my climbing shoes without socks because this gives me slightly better control over my feet while climbing which I particularly need in overhangs.

The problem is that my feet get sweaty and after climbing, the shoes don't smell good. I want to know the best way to clean the inside of my shoes such that the smell disappears. I have tried soaking them in water which helped a bit, but not enough. I am afraid to try soap or other cleaners because it might destroy the fabric or the glue of my shoes.

Can anybody give me some advice how to clean my climbing shoes?

Comment: You might also check out this very similar question: http://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/3668/how-to-clean-rock-climbing-shoes?rq=1