# What to do with chalk when deepwater soloing?

Tags: climbing, climbing-chalk

I have been climbing for a short while and loving it. Now that I've gotten a fair bit of practice with indoor climbing I'm thinking about where this new love of mine can take me. The obvious answers are bouldering and leading outdoors but I've also seen some videos on deepwater soloing.

When I saw these videos I always wondered, what happens to your chalk if you take a chalkbag with you and fall? Do you need to throw whatever chalk remains out after a fall deepwater soloing?

Comment: Related https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/15987/is-it-ok-for-my-climbing-shoes-chalk-bag-to-get-wet

Comment: I feel OP just watched Magnus Midtbø's Tenerife vlog, posted about an hour before this question was asked!

Comment: @GabrielC. nice detective work, you would be right, I did watch that just before posting, though the question had been on my mind for a while

Comment: @BKlassen Not much detective work needed, I watched it too and went "aaw, his chalk's ruined" when he took a fall in that cave.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When you fall into the water with a regular chalk bag, **it will get too wet to be used**. Some solutions to this include,

- [Using liquid chalk](https://upthatrock.com/mallorca-dws-guide-for-newbies/), it [supposed to stick for longer](https://www.thoughtco.com/types-of-climbing-chalk-755591) and you can spread extra on your forearms/legs to rechalk up.
- Multiple chalkbags/extra chalk so that while one bag dries out you can use a new one.
- Leaving the bags in the boat and using the chalk on your hands before you start.

Comment: All the deep water soloing we used to do we just chalked up at the start and saw how far we could get. For all the climbs (up to about 80ft) it was sufficient

Comment: Chris Sharma, Jan Hojer, Jernej Kruder and most of the other pros I've seen usually bring multiple chalkbags for DWS